# Use phplist in another server than the sender's domain

Tags: dns, smtp, spf, phplist

I am trying to use phplist in a different server than the domain that I want to use it as a sender. Is is possible?

To clarify my question:

- my phplist is installed in example.com
- The domain that I want to use as sender is example1.com (in another
  ip than phplist)

I would need some help on how I have to set up my dns settings in both servers.
(In phplist settings I use smtp credentials of info@example1.com)

Please let me know if I need to clarify something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable for a domain to be associated with more than one server in various ways. You don't have to do anything special to send from a different domain, but it would be a very good idea to add the IPs to the SPF record for the domain you're sending from. For outbound you don't have to do anything in DNS - to deal with bounces you can use a return path in your sender domain rather than the from domain.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have ask a good question about adding a new domain to the phplist.

If you  need to set up a new from emails using the domain example1.com, go to campaign setting, and add the new from email address in your case whatever@example1.com.

Also you need to add an spf record to the dns area of example1.com, to allows your IP addresses to send emails from domain example1.com.
you can use spf wizard to generate the spf reccord  https://www.spfwizard.net/

wish that all you need.